# Nao consigo diminuir a quantidade do stock

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-access

Estou tentando diminuir a quantidade do stock no momento da venda e sem successo, usei o codigo abaixo, nenhum erro aparece..

```
Public Sub UpdateDecreaseQuantity()
    Try
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            Dim OtherValue As Integer = 0
            Dim cb As String = "Update Dish SET Quantity = Quantity - @OtherValue"
            con.Open()
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(cb, con)
            Integer.TryParse(row.Cells(2).Value, OtherValue)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OtherValue", OleDbType.Integer).Value = OtherValue
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        cmd.Dispose()
        con.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Não estou vendo problema, sem mais informações não temos como ajudar.

Comment: Não dá nenhum erro, pois NAO diminui o valor "Quantity" na tabela Dish ( esse o problema)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deu certo usando o codigo abaixo:

```
con = New OleDbConnection(cs)
        con.Open()
        Dim cb As String = "update Dish set Quantity = Quantity - '" & Val(DataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value) & "' WHERE ItemID = " & Val(DataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value) & ""
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(cb, con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa debuggar o código para descobrir qual linha não está fazendo o que deveria fazer.

Lendo o código por cima, há dois pontos onde pode estar o problema...

**Primeiro**:

```
Integer.TryParse(row.Cells(2).Value, OtherValue)
```

Você não está verificando se a conversão foi bem sucedida. O método `TryParse` retorna um booleano indicando se deu tudo certo. Você precisa de um `If` para verificar isso.

**Segundo**:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OtherValue", OleDbType.Integer).Value = OtherValue
```

Você deve conferir na documentação se é assim mesmo que se faz pra informar um parâmetro na query. Eu nunca usei OleDb então não sei se está certo. É bom você se informar.