# O textBox Search multiplica os valores de busca

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-access

```
 Private Sub txtSearchByDish_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSearchByDish.TextChanged
    Try
        con = New OleDbConnection(cs)
        con.Open()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT  DishName, I.Rate, SUM([Qty]) as ItemQuantity, BillDate, ( I.Rate * SUM([Qty])) As TotalAmount FROM Dish as I, RestaurantBillingInfo as P, RestaurantBillingItems as PD WHERE DishName like '" & txtSearchByDish.Text & "%' Group By DishName, I.Rate, [Qty], BillDate ORder By DishName", con)
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        dgw.Rows.Clear()
        While (rdr.Read() = True)
            dgw.Rows.Add(rdr(0), rdr(1), rdr(2), rdr(3), rdr(4))
        End While
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Por favor ,explique o que está querendo fazer o seu problema, não ficou muito claro apenas com o título e o trecho de código. Pelo que entendi a cada caracter digitado no textbox você vai ao banco, abre conexão e faz uma query? é Windows forms? Ou Web? Não esqueça de dar dispose nos objetos, ou utilize o Using

Comment: Windows forms; É um form que exibe o relatorio de vendas, e contem la uma textbox para buscar ou mostrar somente alguns items. Ex: se digito PEIXE, irá mostrar apenas a lista com items de nome PEIXE. Espero ter esclarecido....E o meu problema é: ao digitar PEIXE ele multiplica o mesmo Item 9 vezes.....

Comment: Onde ele multiplica? isso que eu nao entendi, ele multiplica na hora que faz o While e adicionar no Seu DataGridview ?

Comment: Exatamente ...PS: o textbox buscar funciona como um filtro de busca.

Comment: Só com estas informações não temos como ajudar. Este código está cheio de erros. Curiosamente você sabe fazer certo (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/261141/101), mas não o fez.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema modificando o meu codigo para:

```
Private Sub txtSearchByDish_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSearchByDish.TextChanged
    Dim totalAmount As Double
    Dim totalQuantity As Integer
    Try
        con = New OleDbConnection(cs)
        con.Open()
        Dim cb As String = "SELECT DishName, I.Rate, SUM([Qty]) as ItemQuantity, BillDate, ( I.Rate * SUM([Qty])) As TotalAmount FROM Dish as I, RestaurantBillingInfo as P, RestaurantBillingItems as PD WHERE I.ItemID = PD.Item_ID AND PD.B_ID=P.BillId AND DishName like '" & txtSearchByDish.Text & "%' Group By DishName, I.Rate, [Qty], BillDate ORder By DishName"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(cb, con)
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        dgw.Rows.Clear()
        Do While (rdr.Read() = True)
            dgw.Rows.Add(rdr(0), rdr(1), rdr(2), rdr(3), rdr(4))
            dgw.Rows.Add(rdr(0), rdr(1), rdr(2), rdr(4))
            totalAmount += rdr(4)
            totalQuantity += rdr(2)
        Loop

        lblQuantity.Text = totalQuantity
        lblTotal.Text = Format(totalAmount, "#,##0.00")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        cmd.Dispose()
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Ele ainda está cheio de problemas, você só não está vendo.

Comment: E porque não dizes onde está o problema???

Comment: Porque são muitos e eu já disse que você sabe fazer certo.

Comment: ok obrigado pela sua GRANDE contribuição.